# Can guest user able to run quiz in moodle

Tags: moodle

i have quiz open for guests ,given permissions to view , preview an attempt the quiz but still guest use can't able to run the test .then why the permissions are mentioned for the guest at quiz level.

Comment: Are those quizzes part of a course open to guests?

Comment: I've created a proposal for a Stack Exchange website for Moodle users and developers. This question would be a perfect fit for it, rather than for Stack Overflow. http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/33861/virtual-learning-environments

Comment: Thanks ,this is definitely helpful

Answer (score 2):

No. The quiz module explicitly checks to make sure the user is logged in.

Answer (score 2):

If you have rights, you can override the permission for the guest role to allow attempts.
Turn on editing, 
edit the quiz, 
click on the override tab, 
choose the guest role 
find the properties specifically to override which is probably "Allow".
Save your changes

Login as guest and check the quiz

Answer (score 0):

When you want reports, etc from "guest" users, then the simple solution:

Make a 'test' user (student role) with 'test' password.
Then make a login-block on the FrontPage, with filled out inputs (username:test, password:test) and a little instruction for guest-users to login with this account.